# Strategy Design Pattern (with argument method) - JAVA

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I'm writing an algorithm which works on a bit serie and do some operations such as shift, AND with it. I wanted to test the algorithm with two different data structure : MutableBigInteger and BitString ( javabdd ), so I thought I'll try to come up with some smart design pattern (since i dont do that a lot) , and I found the strategy design pattern pretty interesting. The only thing that bothers me is that for the function AND, it needs the same type to be computed. I explain with some code :

Theses are my two different class :

```
public class MutableBigInteger {

public void shift();
public void and(MutableBigInteger b2){
    // ...
}
}


public class BitString {

public void shift();
public void and(BitString b2){
    // ...
     }
}
```

I want to make a design so at the creation on my class which does the algorithm I just choose between those classes. The algorithm looks like :

```
while( ... ) {
    bittrain.shift();
    bittrain.and(bittrain2);
}
```

The question for me is how to achieve that with the function AND, since each my own class waits the same class in argument.  I thought I'd like this :

```
public interface BitTrain {

public void shift();
public void and(BitTrain b2);
```

}

and extend my two classes with this interface, but it doesn't really help me because, in MutableBigInteger and BitString I will have to do a cast, I don't really want that (because of speed).

Hoping I had explained it well enough, I wish you a good day !

Nico

Comment: I would suggest correcting the title, because your issue is more about interfaces, inheritance and generics, rather than about strategy pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think this is the cleanest way, but you could use generics:

```
public interface BitTrain<T extends BitTrain<?>> {
    public void shift();
    public void and(T b2);
}
```

And then implement the interface like:

```
public class MutableBigInteger implements BitTrain<MutableBigInteger> {
    public void shift();
    public void and(MutableBigInteger b2){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work with bittrains of different types since `and()` only excepts arguments of the same class. you can't treat them all as Bittrains either, because of wildcard mismatching. I added an answer that will work.

Comment: @Plantface the way I read the question, the OP doesn't want to combine different bittrain implementations...

Comment: @Heuster yes it is a working solution, maybe not the cleanest but I think maybe the fastest... ? In anycase, I valid =) Question : Do i really have to put BitTrain<T extends BitTrain<?>>  OR BitTrain<T> is enough ..? it's just to make sur the implentation extends bittrain, but it is not required ,right ?

Comment: @Nikkolasg it's exactly like that :) but since you want `T` to extend `BitTrain` (I think) it doesn't hurt to make that explicit

Comment: Cool , yeah you're right i'll put it. I'm not used to the "?" symbol in generic classes that's why but it doesnt hurt.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like premature optimization to me. Are you sure that the `checkcast` bytecode would affect your overall performance that much? I think this falls under "HotSpot can do that".

Comment: Maybe it is, I'm not sure, but in my mind it was slower than just polymorphisme techniques, and i need to do theses operations a lot so i really need the fastest way possible.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the question fully , but are you by any chance thinking about the template pattern

```
public class MyBitOperation<T> {

T b1;

public MyBitOperation(T b) {
    b1= b;
}
public void shift(){

//TODO: DO something
}
public void and(T b2){

    //Do somehting else
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what i want to do, but the things is in one of my function (other than shift or "and") I have to call "new" , and i cant do it with generic type ...